# How to merge files horizontally in Windows 7 command prompt?

Tags: windows, bash, merge, command, prompt

I have three files in a directory
File 1:

```
a b
c d
```

File 2:

```
1 2
3 4
```

File 3:

```
e f
g h
```

I know that in windows command prompt, when I type "copy * new.txt", I get a file called new.txt which looks like the following.

```
a b
c d
1 2
3 4
e f
g h
```

In command prompt, how would I combine the files horizontally, so I get the following for my combined file?

```
a b 1 2 e f
c d 3 4 g h
```

Comment: You'll need something more powerful than the command interpreter. Or if you can make the command interpreter do this it will be very messy. Try a scripting language like Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can install some proper (Unix/Linux) tools from [here](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net) and do it like this:

```
paste -d" " file1 file2 file3
a b 1 2 e f
c d 3 4 g h
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

3< File2.txt 4< File3.txt (
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (File1.txt) do (
      set "line1=%%a"
      set /P "line2=" <&3
      set /P "line3=" <&4
      echo !line1! !line2! !line3!
   )
)
```

Further details at [this site](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3126).

- You should use the batch-file tag for any "command prompt" related question.
- You should upvote and select answers that had been useful to you, otherwise the people may refuse to answer your future questions.